# Why do the Death Eaters suddenly abandon Voldemort at the Battle of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

When Harry suddenly reveals that he is alive, the Death Eaters begin to Disapparate, apparently abandoning Voldemort. Why though, when they were at the brink of victory?

Comment: When elephants fight, it is the grass that suffers.

Comment: @Aww Geez and what is that supposed to mean ?

Comment: The Death Eaters may have thought they'd end up collateral damage in the cataclysm that was surely about to happen. Harry has proven himself the immovable object to Voldemort's unstoppable force.

Comment: I think it might be a good idea to start using a "harry-potter-film-series" tag in relevant questions, since JKR has said that the movies exist in their own universe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## They were not certain of victory.

The Death Eaters were not completely assured that Voldemort would indeed win. When Harry seems dead, many are uncertain about approaching him, despite his appearance of death. This implies that even then, they were not completely convinced of Voldemort’s triumph over him.

> “There was complete silence in the clearing. Nobody approached Harry, but he felt their concentrated gaze, it seemed to press him harder into the ground, and he was terrified a finger or an eyelid might twitch.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 (The Flaw in the Plan)*</sup></sub>

The Death Eaters do not Disapparate after Harry reveals himself to be alive in the book, but presumably their motivations for doing so would be similarly rooted in an uncertainty of the outcome. Not knowing who would triumph, those who Disapparated likely chose to flee before they could be killed or sent to Azkaban.

## However, in the book, all remain still.

Though there is an explanation of their actions based on the events of the book, no one is said to Disapparate moments after Harry shows himself to be alive.

> “*‘Protego!’* roared Harry, and the Shield Charm expanded in the middle of the hall, and Voldemort stared around for the source as Harry pulled off the Invisibility Cloak at last.
>
> The yell of shock, the cheers, the screams on every side of ‘Harry!’ ‘HE’S ALIVE!’ were stifled at once. The crowd was afraid, and silence fell abruptly and completely as Voldemort and Harry looked at each other, and began, at the same moment, to circle each other.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 (The Flaw in the Plan)*</sup></sub>

In the book, no Death Eaters are mentioned fleeing until Voldemort is dead, when it is quite certain he will not be victorious.

> “He must speak to the bereaved, clasp their hands, witness their tears, receive their thanks, hear the news now creeping in from every quarter, as the morning drew on, that the Imperiused up and down the country had come back to themselves, **that Death Eaters were fleeing or else being captured,** that the innocent of Azkaban were being released at that very moment, and that Kingsley Shacklebolt had been named temporary Minister for Magic …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 (The Flaw in the Plan)*</sup></sub>

Then, certain that Voldemort has no chance remaining of victory, they escape to avoid imprisonments in Azkaban.